# OrientDB SQL-Traverse for single-direct chain nodes

Tags: orientdb

Suppose the following diagram: I want to traverse from c, walk to all nodes that in the same 'one-direct' chain with C (the blue ones).

But

```
traverse in(), out() from C
```

will also include F and I(the green ones) that i don't want.

How can i do this with sql-traverse?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two TRAVERSE statements and a unionAll(), eg.

```
 SELECT expand(unionAll($a, $b))
 LET 
   $a = (traverse out() from C)
   $b = (traverse in() from C)
```

Comment: both "traverse out() from C" and "traverse in() from C" are not empty, but  with the the above code, orientdb just return empty, how can i identify the problem?

Comment: I just updated my answer, probably the expand() will fix the problem.